# Make two divs be resizable at the same time inside a map

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an array named `products`, that has 4 different products. By mapping it, I created 4 different resizable divs, like this:

```
 {products.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <div key={index} style={{ margin: "8px 0px 0px 0px", display: "flex" }}>
                    <div className="resizable-switch-column"> 
                        <div className="switch-container">
                          <div className="switch-bar"/>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
```

**My question is:**, how can I resize all of those divs at the same time? If I resize the second one, for example, all the other 3 divs must be resized at once.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.switch-container {
  background-color: var(--background-secondary);
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: auto 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.switch-bar{
  background-color: var(--color-primary-chrome20);
  border: 1px var(--color-primary-lighten2) solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 1px);
  overflow: auto;
  height: 14px;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.switch-bar::-webkit-resizer {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

[This](https://gyazo.com/dd91651715387e03aae9789e31dec4a1) is how it works at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store the width inline with the useState hook.

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState('100%');

<div style={{width: width}} yourDraggingFunction={() => whenDragging()} />

const whenDragging = () => setWidth(someWidthVariable);
```

Think of this as more pseudo code and don't take it so literally. The goal is to manipulate a single state variable regardless of the which element you resize.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
That seems to work, but not the way I intended. It sets the width only after a re-render (F5 in the page, for example), it doesn't update at once.